# Dropdown menu colour not restoring after hovering out of the submenu div downwards

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

This is an interesting one.

The CSS:

```
    #menu>li>a:link, #menu>li>a:visited {
        color:#002349;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: auto;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-transform: lowercase;
        padding: 10px 10px;
    }

    #menu>li:hover>a {
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #002349;
    }

.submenu {
    position:absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    top:32px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #002349;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 20;
}

#menu li:hover .submenu {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
}

.submenu li {
    text-align: left !important;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    padding: 0px;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}

.submenu li a:link, .submenu li a:visited {
    color:#fff !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:5px 12px 7px 12px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.submenu li a:hover, .submenu li a:active {
    color:#fff !important;
    background: #666 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="http://jamie.brixwork.com/why-jamie-realtor" title="Meet Jamie MacDougall">why jamie</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://jamie.brixwork.com/why-sothebys" title="Why Sotheby's International?">why sotheby's</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://jamie.brixwork.com/listings" title="Featured Real Estate Listings">featured listings</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="http://jamie.brixwork.com/listings/pageid-8/city-North+Vancouver/page-1" title="Featured Real Estate Listings">North Vancouver</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://jamie.brixwork.com/listings/pageid-9/city-West+Vancouver/page-1" title="Featured Real Estate Listings">West Vancouver</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can see the whole page here:
http://jamie.brixwork.com/why-sothebys

Go over the "listings" menu with your mouse. If your mouse exits UPWARDS or SIDEWAYS, the original text colour (dark blue) comes back.

However if you proceed to the dropdown menu () and then exit by moving mouse downwards out of the submenu, the text colour of the top menu doesn't change back.

Why would this be? I have the :hover on the top

tag because I want the hover effect to be in effect on the top menu item while the submenu is hovered so I can't put the hover effect only on the  tag of the top menu.

Comment: Could you perhaps give the css and jquery/javascript of the dropdown too?  How exactly do you change the font color to white?  Via css?  Via a jquery script?  Simply more code is needed to answer this question.

Comment: Roger that = updated the CSS.

Comment: He is using css to control the menu; there is no javascript. Hover over the menu li and it will show the submenu

Comment: Currently working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/eEE8f/  Why not on website .. 0_o

Comment: Yup it's all JS. I know this is one of those bizarre things. I wonder if it's some weird thing with browser behaviour that I can't get around. 

Funny thing is, after i hover in and out to make it go all white, and look at the firebug status, it says it SHOULD be color:#002349 which is the deep blue, so I can't even troubleshoot which line of CSS is causing this weird behaviour... :)(

Comment: Yeah I know I noticed that too- still working on it though...

Comment: What is the cufon element? The link color may be going back to the right color but I think the cufon where the text is might not be

Comment: CUFON font replacement.. maybe I should try disabling CUFON then.

Comment: Yup CUFON error. Grrrr. Does anybody know how to resolve this in scope of CUFON? The design will be absurd without the right font..

Comment: does including the custom font in the css cause errors?

Comment: FAQ #10 had the answer... https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/FAQ#wiki-faq-10

Comment: Exiting via that cufon isn't triggering the :hover to turn off.  You could fix it by using just a bit of js to show the menu instead I think.

Comment: Cufon.replace('#menu>li', { fontFamily: 'gillsans', hover:true,
hoverables: { li: true },
 ignore: { ul: true },
 textless: { li: true }
});

Comment: GJ!  Is your question answered now that you found the FAQ result or do you want a JS solution?

Comment: No, but thank you so much. I'll settle for waht works and move onto finishing the site... it's been long enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/FAQ#wiki-faq-10

Turns out it was a CUFON issue where the detection is off. FAQ #10 has the answer.. although I don't even understand whatever that means. :(  But copy-pasting a snippet from their example solved it.

I changed my CUFON replacement code to:

```
Cufon.replace('#menu>li', { fontFamily: 'gillsans', hover:true,
hoverables: { li: true },
    ignore: { ul: true },
    textless: { li: true }
});
```